# “ Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'initialize' of undefined” when running ng test command and error shows at parse.initialize

Tags: angular, back4app, parse-dashboard

I am using angular 4 and parse database and I am trying to implement test scripts and run using ng test command.

It returns initialize error in app.component.ts page at parse.initialize()

and error is

> " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'initialize' of undefined"

I implemented sample test script below in contact component

**contact.component.spec.ts:**

```
it(should have as text 'contact page', async(() => {

expect(comp.text).toEqual('contact page');

}));
```

and my **app.component.ts:**

```
Parse.initialize("myAppId", "myMasterKey");

Parse.serverURL = 'http://localhost:1337/api/';

Parse.masterKey = appConfig.masterKey;
```

Comment: Have you imported Parse with `const Parse = require('parse/node');`?

Comment: it's Worked for me when i add like these import {Parse} from 'parse';